# сохранение текста IULabel при переходе на другой UIController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiviewcontroller

Есть класс UIView с UILabel и UITexfield. Передаю значение из последнего на лэйбл. При переходе на другой контроллер, ожидаемо текст не обновляется на введенный.

Можно ли его сохранить без создания UserDefaults и подобного? необходимо держать инфо только на время работы приложения.

Comment: Создайте синглтон или глобальную переменную, видимую во всех контроллерах. Но это плохая практика. Лучше все-таки где-то хранить или передавать при переходе.

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите обновить лэйбл на другом контроллере? тогда вам нужно достучаться до лэйбла именного нужного вам контроллера и установить ему значение из вашего текстфилда перед тем как сделать пуш/пресент.
Если же вы хотите обновить лейбл на предидущем экране по возвращению то тут несколько способов (ведь кнопка назад просто дизмиссит контроллер). Для этого вы можете, например, переопределись действия кнопки назад ( что бы перед тем как закрыть контроллер она обновила лейбл на прошлом экране ), вы можете обновить лейбл через замыкание, или можете обновить лейбл во viewWillAppear.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! я так понимаю, что во viewWillAppear логичнее всего. У меня есть функция передающая текст из UITextfield в UILabel и сохраняющая данные в UserDefault. но я не понимаю, как вызвать во viewWillAppear загрузку обновленных данных именно этого лейбла. У меня разделены UIView и ViewController